# Showing $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 3 + 4i \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$: how to guess?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

(I think I understand how to show $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle5\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ using the Chinese remainder theorem.)

---

I don't know how to "identify the structure of the additive group" of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 3 + 4i \rangle$. The answer is apparently $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$, and the solutions say to show that
$$ \phi : \mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 3 + 4i \rangle \to \mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z} \qquad \text{given by} \qquad a + ib \mapsto a - 7b $$
is an isomorphism. There are a few things I note:

- $7^2 = -1 \mod{25}$
- $\phi(3 + 4i) = 0$
- $25 = 3^2 + 4^2$

But, I can't put the pieces together. What I want to know is:

- *Why is it 25 in $25 \mathbb{Z}$?*
- *How can we guess to send $a + ib$ to $a - 7b$?*

Comment: $(3+4i)$ contains $(3+4i)(3-4i)=25$ and $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(3+4i)=\Bbb{Z}[i]/(3+4i,25)=\Bbb{Z}[i]/(18+i,25)\cong \Bbb{Z}/(25)$

Comment: @reuns Where does $18+i$ come from?

Comment: multiplying by $6$ and I meant $18-i$ sorry